# Building an Error-Prone OpenAI API Wrapper with Rate Limiting for Asynchronous Tasks in Python

Tags: python, django, openai-api, rate-limiting

StackOverflow community!

I'm working on a Django project where I need to build a robust and efficient wrapper around the OpenAI API for asynchronous tasks. My main goals are:

**API Wrapper Design:** To create classes that effectively wrap the OpenAI API, enabling model selection and prompt generation.

**Rate Limiting:** Implementations to handle rate limits, specifically for both tokens per minute and requests per minute.

**Asynchronous Task Management:** Utilize asynchronous tasks, possibly with Celery, to manage API calls without exceeding the rate limits.

Here's what I've conceptualized so far:

**Wrapper Class:** A class that handles the connection to the OpenAI API, including methods for selecting models and sending prompts.

**Prompt Generation:** Classes or methods dedicated to constructing and managing prompt structures.

**Rate Limiting:** Implementing a system to track and control the rate of API requests, possibly integrating with the Celery task queue. (Using Redis as Token Bucket? I have the feeling my implementation sometimes does not work correctly if somehow several worker block and write the same tokenbucket at the same time). (Celery Worker Concurrency is 1, but still I am getting on a different API "Too Many Requests" even if my TokenBucket has the right amount of it).

My questions are:

**Best Practices:** Are there any recommended patterns or best practices for building such a wrapper, especially concerning error handling and efficiency?

**Rate Limiting Techniques:** What are the most effective ways to implement rate limiting in this context, considering both tokens per minute and requests per minute? How to know amount of tokens required before an request has been send?

**Asynchronous Integration:** How can I integrate Celery or another asynchronous framework to manage the task queue without violating rate limits?

Any suggestions, code examples, or resources would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

My TokenBucket Class:

```
class TokenBucketManager:
def __init__(self, endpoint, tokens, ttl, high_frequency=False):
    self.redis = caches["token_cache"]
    self.endpoint = endpoint
    self.tokens = tokens
    self.ttl = ttl
    self.high_frequency = high_frequency
    
def _bucket_key(self):
    return f"token_bucket:{self.endpoint}"

def _keepalive_key(self):
    return f"token_bucket_keepalive:{self.endpoint}"

def _sync_key(self):
    return f"token_bucket_sync:{self.endpoint}"

def token_bucket_exists(self):
    bucket_key = self._bucket_key() 
    return self.redis.has_key(bucket_key)

def keep_token_alive(self):
    keep_alive_key = self._keepalive_key()
    token_bucket_key = self._bucket_key()
    sync_key = self._sync_key()
    task_token_bucket.apply_async(
        countdown=self.ttl - 1, 
        kwargs={"keep_alive_key": keep_alive_key, "token_bucket_key": token_bucket_key, "sync_key":sync_key, "ttl": self.ttl, "tokens": self.tokens, "is_sync": False}, 
        queue="token_handler"
        )
    return keep_alive_key
    
def set_token_bucket(self):
    key = self._bucket_key()
    with self.redis.lock(key):
        if not self.redis.has_key(key):
            self.redis.set(key, self.tokens, self.ttl)
            self.keep_token_alive() 
            logger.info(f"Setting token bucket for {key} with {self.tokens} tokens and ttl {self.ttl}")
    
def consume_if_possible(self, amount=1):
    
    if not self.token_bucket_exists():
        self.set_token_bucket()
        
    token_bucket_key = self._bucket_key()
    keep_alive_key = self._keepalive_key()
    self.redis.set(keep_alive_key, 1, self.ttl * 2)
    if self.redis.has_key(token_bucket_key):
        with self.redis.lock(token_bucket_key):
            tokens_left = self.redis.get(token_bucket_key)
            if tokens_left is not None and tokens_left > amount:
                try:
                    self.redis.decr(token_bucket_key, amount)
                except:
                    return False 
                return True
            else:
                return False
    else:
        return False 


def get_tokens_ttl(self):
    ttl = self.redis.ttl(self._bucket_key())
    return ttl if ttl > 0 else self.ttl


def sync_bucket_to_external_api(self, retry_after):
    if self.high_frequency:
        pass 
    logger.info(f"Syncing token bucket for {self._bucket_key()} to external API, Retry After: {retry_after}")
    token_bucket_key = self._bucket_key()
    sync_key = self._sync_key()
    keepalive_key = self._keepalive_key()
    with self.redis.lock(token_bucket_key):
        self.redis.set(token_bucket_key, 0, retry_after)
    self.redis.set(sync_key, 1, self.ttl * 2)
    task_token_bucket.apply_async(
        countdown=retry_after,
        kwargs={"keep_alive_key": keepalive_key, "token_bucket_key": token_bucket_key, "sync_key":sync_key, "ttl": self.ttl, "tokens": self.tokens, "is_sync": True},
        queue="token_handler")
```

Another Celery Task to refresh the tokenbucket as long as needed:

```
  @shared_task(bind=True)
  def task_token_bucket(self, keep_alive_key, token_bucket_key, 
  sync_key, ttl, tokens, is_sync=False):
redis = caches["token_cache"]

if redis.has_key(sync_key):
    if not is_sync:
        return 
    else:
        with redis.lock(sync_key):
            if redis.has_key(sync_key):
                redis.delete(sync_key)
            else:
                return
        
if redis.has_key(keep_alive_key):
    with redis.lock(token_bucket_key, 30):
        if redis.has_key(token_bucket_key):
            redis.set(token_bucket_key, tokens, ttl)
            redis.delete(keep_alive_key)
            logger.info(f"Token bucket for {token_bucket_key} refreshed.")
            task_token_bucket.apply_async(
                countdown=ttl,
                kwargs={"keep_alive_key": keep_alive_key, "sync_key": sync_key, "token_bucket_key": token_bucket_key, "ttl": ttl, "tokens": tokens},
                queue="token_handler"
            )
            logger.info(f"Renewal task for token bucket {token_bucket_key} scheduled.")
        else:
            logger.info(f"Token bucket for {token_bucket_key} not refreshed.")
else:
    logger.info(f"Token bucket for {token_bucket_key} not refreshed.")
```